# How to generate RSA private key with OpenSSL that includes DEK header

Tags: openssl, certificate, private-key

I am trying to generate a private ley and CSR with OpenSSL, to submit to an internal AD CA, for which the resulting certificate will be used on a Cisco Catalyst 9200 switch.

The only way the key can be imported to the switch is if it includes a DEK header.

I am able to use the below OpenSSL command to add the header after the initial key generation:

```
openssl rsa -in keyin.key -out keyout.key -des3
```

I am wondering how I can include this header during the inital creation of the key, to save myself a step. Here is the command I currently use to generate the key and CSR initially:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "CERT_DETAILS" -sha256 -keyout keyout.key -out csr.csr -config san_cert.cnf
```

Comment: In OpenSSL only 'traditional' privatekey formats are encrypted using the Proc-Type and DEK-Info headers, and `rsa` writes traditional formats for RSA (either encrypted or unencrypted) (`pkey -traditional` writes them for all algorithms). Since 1.0.0 in 2010 `req -newkey -keyout` writes _PKCS8_ format which is encrypted by changing PEM label: `BEGIN/END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` instead of `BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY`. Unless you want to go back to an 0.9.x version from the days of Bill Clinton or Dubya Bush, you can't do it in one step. Also this is not programming or development.